# Simple kinematics excercise, throwing something upwards

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I am trying to solve this simple excercise:

**Question**

*You throw a small coin upwards with* $4 \frac{m}{s}$ *. How much time does it need to reach the height of* $0.5 m$ *? Why do we get two results?*

**Answer**

(We get two results for time, because the coin passes the 0.5m mark downwards too.)

The equtation I used (for constant acceleration):
$x = x_0 + v_0 t + \frac{1}{2} a t^2$

These values I know: $x = 0.5m$, $x_0 = 0$, $v_0 = 4 \frac{m}{s}$, $a = -9.81 \frac{m}{s^2}$ So, I get a quadratic equtation which I can solve for $t$. My two results are: $t_1 = 0.15s$ and $t_2 = 0.66s$, however the book has the results 0.804s and 0.013s. What am I doing wrong?

**Thanks for your help**

Comment: your answer is correct. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+.5+%3D+4t+-(9.8/2)t^2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing, your book did it wrong.

Comment: But if the question had asked for the times when a height of 0.05 m was reached, the book's answers would be correct. Sounds like a typo in the problem.